# cut out array value and fill it with var i

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a question about an array-value. I want to have the following code:

```
cubes[0].animate({ top: fixedOffs.top+row*20, left: fixedOffs.left-row*5, 'background-color': '#1f2c8a'}, Math.floor(Math.random()*1800));
cubes[1].animate({ top: fixedOffs.top+row*20, left: fixedOffs.left-row*4, 'background-color': '#3d809a'}, Math.floor(Math.random()*1800));
cubes[2].animate({ top: fixedOffs.top+row*20, left: fixedOffs.left-row*3, 'background-color': '#1f2c8a'}, Math.floor(Math.random()*1800));
cubes[3].animate({ top: fixedOffs.top+row*20, left: fixedOffs.left-row*2, 'background-color': '#510000'}, Math.floor(Math.random()*1800));
// until ...
cubes[300].animate({ top: fixedOffs.top+row*20, left: fixedOffs.left-row*4, 'background-color': '#3d809a'}, Math.floor(Math.random()*1800));
```

what I want to do is cut the integer out and fill it with `i` in a for loop.

something like:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
cubes[i].animate({ top: fixedOffs.top+row*20, left: fixedOffs.left-row*5, 'background-color': '#1f2c8a'}, Math.floor(Math.random()*1800));
cubes[i].animate({ top: fixedOffs.top+row*20, left: fixedOffs.left-row*4, 'background-color': '#3d809a'}, Math.floor(Math.random()*1800));
cubes[i].animate({ top: fixedOffs.top+row*20, left: fixedOffs.left-row*3, 'background-color': '#1f2c8a'}, Math.floor(Math.random()*1800));
cubes[i].animate({ top: fixedOffs.top+row*20, left: fixedOffs.left-row*2, 'background-color': '#510000'}, Math.floor(Math.random()*1800));
// until ...
cubes[i].animate({ top: fixedOffs.top+row*20, left: fixedOffs.left-row*4, 'background-color': '#3d809a'}, Math.floor(Math.random()*1800)); 
}
```

its because I dont want to type every single number until 300 in it.
There should be something like a function which finds the square-brackets and fills it with the numbers. The hard thing on it, the animate-properties are different on every cube. (but I already have them)

Thanks

Comment: You need to provide a formula for calculating the `left` property. I cannot see any pattern right now.

Comment: its not about the animate function. I already have the code for all this. Its just that I have to insert all numbers of the array by hand. and I dont want to do this. because in some cases there are like 600.

Comment: Please specify in your question what the variables are that need to change per iteration of the loop and how you need them to change.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you're not trying to cut down the number of lines of code, you just want to get rid of the hardcoded array indices. That should be easy. Just declare `var i = 0;` and then replace every index with `i++`, e.g. `cubes[i++].animate(...);`

Comment: @ChrisP the variable i stands for each number 0 - 300. I dont want to fill every number until 300 by hand, thats why I want to do it in a loop, log me and copy and paste it.

Comment: @EiríkurFannarTorfason exactly, thats my point. And if you could say to me how I could get rid of the numbers and replace it with i++, that would be awesome.

Comment: @supersize , I would probably use a text editor that supports regular expressions for finding and replacing text. One such text editor is notepad++. Search for `cubes\[\d+\]` and replace it with `cubes[i++]`

Comment: @EiríkurFannarTorfason Im using dreamweaver, but it doesnt find cubes\[\d+\]

Comment: @supersize I don't have access to dreamweaver but I understand it supports regular expressions. Did you check the 'Use regular expression' checkbox? Also, it should be `cubes\[\d+\]` since [ and ] are reserved characters in regular expressions and need to be escaped to be mathced. Perhaps you will find this [tutorial](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/regular_expressions_pt2.html) helpful.

Comment: @EiríkurFannarTorfason awesome, got it! Thanks for saving loads of time. If you do it as an answer I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introduce an index variable `i` and increment it with every array access like so:

```
var i = 0;
cubes[i++].animate({ top: fixedOffs.top+row*20, left: fixedOffs.left-row*5, 'background-color': '#1f2c8a'}, Math.floor(Math.random()*1800));
cubes[i++].animate({ top: fixedOffs.top+row*20, left: fixedOffs.left-row*4, 'background-color': '#3d809a'}, Math.floor(Math.random()*1800));
cubes[i++].animate({ top: fixedOffs.top+row*20, left: fixedOffs.left-row*3, 'background-color': '#1f2c8a'}, Math.floor(Math.random()*1800));
cubes[i++].animate({ top: fixedOffs.top+row*20, left: fixedOffs.left-row*2, 'background-color': '#510000'}, Math.floor(Math.random()*1800));
// until ...
cubes[i++].animate({ top: fixedOffs.top+row*20, left: fixedOffs.left-row*4, 'background-color': '#3d809a'}, Math.floor(Math.random()*1800));
```

Using a text editor that supports regular expressions, you can replace your existing hardcoded indices with `i++` by searching for `cubes\[\d+\]` and replacing it with `cubes[i++]`.

Answer (score 1):

Save the variable properties somewhere:

```
var props = [
  { left : 5, bgColor: '#123' },
  { left : 4, bgColor: '#456' },
  { left : 2, bgColor: '#fff' },
  ...
  { left : 3, bgColor: '#f00' } 
];
```

Then use a loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < cubes.length; i++) {
  cubes[i].animate(
    { 
      top: fixedOffs.top+row*20,
      left: fixedOffs.left-row * props[i].left,
      'background-color': props[i].bgColor
    },
    Math.floor(Math.random()*1800)
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.eq()`

`.get()` and `[]` return the native dom element, not a jQuery collection.

And if you're going to animate 300 things, i suggest you drop jQuery.